# What is a use case for an unordered Binary Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Does anyone use unordered Binary Trees?

I don't see any advantage to using an unordered Binary Tree over an array.

Comment: One advantage over an array is that it can grow dynamically. Of course, you give up direct indexing in exchange for that. There are more similarities to a linked list, though. How did this question even come up?

Comment: It's a good question. Basically, I think that tree can be used to maintain parent-child relationship in general. Recently, I came to know about Merkle tree data structure, which could be considered as un-order binary tree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree

Comment: Binary trees are only used where the order of nodes is important, although the order isn't necessarily sorted by key.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I was looking into the difference between Binary Trees, Binary Search Trees and Red-Black Trees.

Comment: Haha I found the answer - Used to implement a Heap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: @BSeven: I wanted to mention Heap too. And now looking at your comment, I believe I should have. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To represent a simple expression language with operators of at most two arguments.

```
  +
 / \
3   *
   / \
  4   5
```

Comment: This is a very good example, because this is not only an unordered binary tree but also there is no concept of 'order' in expression trees.

Comment: This is ordered by operator precedence.

Comment: @Pod a good remark. I think I considered _unordered (array)_ to mean that `3+4*5` would result in any tree that flattened again as `3+4*5`. That would allow two trees. The precedence hence does indeed not fit. Consider the precedence an other aspect. Indeed the tree of `(3+4)*5` would need not introduce `()`.

Answer (score 2):

> *Generating Unordered Binary Trees is necessary in both the graph theory and in different applications. For example, a list of all trees with a given number of internal nodes can be used in computer science to test or analyze an algorithm for its correctness or computational complexity.*

<sub>[*Source*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24767-8_68)</sub>