# Appropriate datastructure to use for children of a tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, unordered

So I wanted to implement a strict definition of a tree - a graph without any cycles. Recursively it is a node with n subtrees/children. Each node will thus need some kind of data structure to associate it with its n subtrees.

- Arrays, lists, sequences, ordered collections: Children do not really have orderings. There is a special type of tree called an "ordered tree" that does associate some kind of ordering to the children of a node, but this doesn't seem appropriate here.

  For example:

  `Tree(3,
    Tree(4), 
    Tree(5)
  ) == Tree(3,
    Tree(5),
    Tree(4)
  )`
- Set: A set is not ordered, but it also doesn't hold duplicates. Functionally it would make sense if Tree(3) == Tree(3), but we want duplicate information because a node can have more than one Tree(3) as a subtree.

  For example:

  `Tree(3,
    Tree(4)
  ) != Tree(3,
    Tree(4),
    Tree(4)
  )`
- Bag: A unordered collection which allows for items to be added, but does not allow for any removals. This doesn't seem to consistent with the fact that children from a tree can be removed.

Are there any other unordered datastructures that might be more suitable? I'm sure this has been an issue before, and what are common solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what have you tried so far - an unordered would be done with hardcoding the linkage between nodes and it's child. - like a binary tree. If you want an ordered tree then you may try BST or Max/Min heap. You can look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598967/what-is-a-use-case-for-an-unordered-binary-tree

Comment: Hardcoding seems to only really work if you have something like BinTree where there is a fixed amount of children rather than some variable amount of children. I guess one way might to just represent the whole thing like a graph where there are vertices and nodes. But that gets rid of the guaranteed no cycle rule. I feel like there might be an elegant solution here like a hashmap, but that would require that everything has some hashing defined.

Comment: A very useful data structure is a [left-child, right-sibling binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree). This lets you represent any type of tree, with an arbitrary number of children per node, very simply.

Comment: I am sure this will however make equality comparisons difficult since the contents of the linked lists of siblings will need to be checked regardless of order. I feel like a hashtable might be best for equality comparisons later down the line.

Answer (score 0):

If children order doesn't matter and duplication is allowed, I think `List` will suffice.

As there is no guaranty the children will be ordered inside the list or inserted in correct order and also a `Set` can not be used because of duplication is allowed, we can define how two tree will be compared so that `Tree(3, ArrayList(Tree(4), Tree(5))` and `Tree(3, ArrayList(Tree(5), Tree(4))` can be compared as equal.

One way is - while comparing if they are equal, we can sort the children based on their value and compare them recursively.

```
class Tree {
    private Integer value;
    private List<Tree> children;

    // getter for value
    // getter for children

    public Tree(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof Tree)) {
            return false;
        }
        Tree otherTree = (Tree) other;

        return equalUtil(this, otherTree);
    }

    private boolean equalUtil(Tree lhs, Tree rhs) {
        if(lhs == null && rhs == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if(lhs == null || rhs == null) {
            return false;
        }


        if(lhs.children.size() != rhs.children.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        // copying the children into another list to not altering
        // the tree's data ordering
        lhsChildren = lhs.children;
        Collections.sort(lhsChildren, new TreeComparator());

        rhsChildren = rhs.children;
        Collections.sort(rhsChildren, new TreeComparator());

        for(int i = 0; i < lhsChildren.size(); i++) {
            if(!equalUtil(lhsChildren[i], rhsChildren[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }

    static class TreeComparator implements Comparator<Tree> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Tree lhs, Tree rhs) {
            return lhs.getValue().compareTo(rhs.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi this would seem to make comparisons brute force, as Tree(3, ArrayList(Tree(4), Tree(5)) != Tree(3, ArrayList(Tree(5), Tree(4)) when they should really be. I guess you could keep both arraylists ordered, but there is no guarantee that the value the Tree is encapsulating will have an ordering.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Now I understood your question. Let me update my answer